# How to send a string to a smart contract using mxpy and shell script?

Tags: multiversx

How can I send a string in arguments to a smart contract using a shell script and mxpy ? I’ve been trying to use str:“My string to send” as an argument to mxpy call but it doesn’t work I’ve also been trying other technics.

I can’t find the way to do it, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

`str:` should be inside the quotes

Therefore `str:“My string to send”` is wrong, `"str:My string to send"` is the correct way to do that

Example:

```
mxpy --verbose contract call <contract's address> --recall-nonce \
--pem=<pem's path> \
--gas-limit=<your gas limit> \
--proxy=<proxy's url> \
--chain=<chain's id> \
--function="MyFunction" \
--arguments "str:My string to send" \
--send --wait-result
```